# How to Basically Add the Values of Two <Button> tags

Tags: javascript, html

I think I got the logic part right, another problem I have is the NaN output that I keep receiving when I click on the `<button>` tags. I did use addEventListener('click') method but it seems more complicated, so I tried this simple codes instead. I'm just having trouble on how to add the values of the buttons, any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code :

```
<html>


<body>

<script type = "text/javascript">

 function test(value)
{
    var val = parseFloat(value);
    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById('totaltext').value);

    document.getElementById('totaltext').innerHTML =  total + val;
} 

</script>


total : <p id = "totaltext" value = "0">0</p>
<button value = "10.11" name = "product" id = "button1" onClick = "test(this.value);">value1</button>


<button value = "20.00" name = "product" id = "button2" onClick = "test(this.value);">value2</button>



</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7tm161ob/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the elements you are accessing `button` is not an input tag, the value attribute is not the correct one. `value` is considered an html attribute in this case that is not directly available in the JavaScript object.

You will need to use the method `.getAttribute()` to get those values. Here is how it works.

```
<button value="10.11" name="product" id="button1" onclick="test(this);">value1</button>

<button value="20.00" name="product" id="button2" onclick="test(this);">value2</button>

function test(button) {
    var val = parseFloat(button.getAttribute("value"));
    var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('totaltext').getAttribute("value"));

    document.getElementById('totaltext').innerHTML =  total + val;
    document.getElementById('totaltext').setAttribute("value",total + val)
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7tm161ob/3/)

Comment: I see now, so that was what I was missing. It works now, the values are appearing and changing the value of the <p>. However, they still don't add. I tried : 
if(button.clicked)
 totalvalue = document.getElementById('totaltext').getAttribute("value");
 totalvalue = total + val;
    document.getElementById('totaltext').innerHTML = totalvalue;
but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try the example on jsfiddle it seems to be adding the values now.

Comment: Been solving it for myself using if(button.getAttribute("name") === 'product') statements with total - val... but I still can't do it. The code is adding, yes, but I can't make them stop stacking. Is there a way to make them stop stacking?